# Plot a generic function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have the following mathematical function in Python:

```
y = max(0, |x| - epsilon)
```

To plot it I have done the usual

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-100,100,400)
y = np.maximum(0, np.absolute(x) - 10)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

but I want to plot it without assigning any value to `epsilon` as shown in the picture
[image: error func]

Comment: What would you want to plot? `y` is an entire *family* of functions, one function for each value of `epsilon`. Looking at it anther way, `y` is a higher-order function whose limit as epsilon approaches 0 is `y = |x|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the value of `epsilon`, then you can do it using `plt.xticks`:

```py
epsilon = 10
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 10000)
y = np.maximum(0, np.absolute(x) - epsilon)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks([-epsilon, epsilon], ["$-\\varepsilon$", "$\\varepsilon$"])
plt.plot()
```

If you don't, then you can just determine its value using `y`:

```py
epsilon = x[y == 0][-1]
```

And then applying the code above.